# Change part of style by jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I try to change the style of a specific part by jQuery, surprisingly it doesn't work.

The simple process of changing style is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
});
```

and based on the previous line, I try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prdctfltr-2 > div > form > div.prdctfltr_filter_wrapper.prdctfltr_columns_1 > div > div.prdctfltr_filter.prdctfltr_product_cat.prdctfltr_attributes.prdctfltr_single.pf_style_6057cdf153466.prdctfltr_terms_customized.prdctfltr_terms_customized_select > div.prdctfltr_add_scroll.prdctfltr_max_height.prdctfltr_down").css({"display": "none", "max-height": "auto"});
});
```

But it doesn't work, and the `max-height` and `display` do not change.

I add the line in the `header` between `<script></script>`.

Update: You may find the code in

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prdctfltr-2 > div > form > div.prdctfltr_filter_wrapper.prdctfltr_columns_1 > div > div.prdctfltr_filter.prdctfltr_product_cat.prdctfltr_attributes.prdctfltr_single.pf_style_6057cdf153466.prdctfltr_terms_customized.prdctfltr_terms_customized_select > div.prdctfltr_add_scroll.prdctfltr_max_height.prdctfltr_down").css({"display": "none", "max-height": "auto"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 150px; display: block;">


</div>
```

Comment: Also why are you setting display to none and also using max-height?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is less than optimal as a problem description. Please [edit] your question with a [mre] and a description of how it "doesn't work". You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable example just like a jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey, I edit the question, as you see, I try to change `max-height` and `display`, and it doesn't work means these two do not change.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei Your snippet lacks jQuery (edit the snippet and select a jQuery version from the sidebar), and your selector has six child combinators, but you only show a single element instead of seven; not a [mre] yet. If `$("#prdctfltr-2 > div > form > div.prdctfltr_filter_wrapper.prdctfltr_columns_1 > div > div.prdctfltr_filter.prdctfltr_product_cat.prdctfltr_attributes.prdctfltr_single.pf_style_6057cdf153466.prdctfltr_terms_customized.prdctfltr_terms_customized_select > div.prdctfltr_add_scroll.prdctfltr_max_height.prdctfltr_down").length === 0`, then there is no such element.

Answer (score -1):

Add an id and add your own changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div").css({"display": "none", "max-height": "auto"});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" class="prdctfltr_add_scroll prdctfltr_max_height prdctfltr_down" style="height: 150px; display: block;">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```